# Library for handwriting analysis in Python

Tags: library, python

I would like to analyse handwriting from a stylus (pen). I have recorded the x and y positions as well as the pressure while persons have been writing. Now, I would like to infer if a person is writing oblique or straight and the degree of obliqueness.

For this purpose I'm searching a library in Python which can determine the obliqueness of handwritten text and optionally other statistics related to handwriting.

Comment: Did you try Googling? I did and got lots of relevant hits.

Comment: @EricShain Yes, I did. I have googled for "python writing slant" and "python handwriting analysis" but I did not find any good library. There are a lot of tutorials how to do OCR but that is not what I want.

Comment: What about https://towardsdatascience.com/handwriting-recognition-using-tensorflow-and-keras-819b36148fe5 and https://niektemme.com/2016/02/21/tensorflow-handwriting/ Both talk about using TensorFlow.

Comment: By the way I googled with "handwriting analysis python".